# Condas environment does not include pandas

Tags: python, pandas, conda

I have created a conda environment:

```
conda create -n nnlibs
```

and installed some libraries on it. While trying to run a code I found out there's no pandas installed on this environment.

```
>>>import pandas
No module named 'pandas'
```

and running `conda list | grep pandas` returns nothing. My `base` environment however seems to have a working pandas. Other libraries like Numpy and Scipy are intact on both environments.

Is there a way to fix this without re-building the environment or reinstalling the packages? I have installed a lot of libraries and I'd rather fix this environment if possible.

Comment: `conda create -n nnlibs` means in words: conda please create an empty environment with the name `nnlibs`. If you want the same environment as you would get from the anaconda installer you would have to request the `anaconda` meta package: `conda create -n nnlibs anaconda`

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to use the anaconda meta package in/with this environment?

Comment: If you want to use it, you need to install it manually: `conda install -n nnlibs anaconda` would install all the packages you would get by default in the anaconda installer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by installing the library manually:

```
conda install -c anaconda pandas
```

as @cel explained in the comments, this happened because 
    `conda create -n nnlibs` 
creates an empty environment. While I managed to solve the problem by installing each package manually, a better way (as @cel suggested) would be to run:

```
conda install -n nnlibs anaconda
```